# A Regular expression for validating Range-like expressions

Tags: c#, regex

I'm having trouble building a regular expression because I'm really a noob to the subject.

The goal is to validate 'range' expressions from the user input, like this:

- 20-30 (between 20 and 30)
- 11,12 (2 and 4)
- -10 (smaller than 10)
- 80- (larger than 80)

or combinations of any number of those, like:

-10,11,12,20-30,80-

I'm already able to parse the different components from a string like this using the following
regular expressions (and calling .GetMatches()):

```
var rangeRegex = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)?-\d+(\.\d+)?");
var smallerThanRegex = new Regex(@"(?<![\d\.])-\d+(\.\d+)?");
var greaterThanRegex = new Regex(@"\d+(\.\d+)?-(?!\d)");
```

I'm just not sure on how to combine them into a big Regex that can be used to validate whether a string is a valid 'range expression'.

Is there anyone who knows how to do this without wasting an entire week on it (like I would)? Thank you very much in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This would be the regex to check the syntax, it has no ideas about the semantics of the string!

```
^(?<=\D|^)(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?-|\d+(?:\.\d+)?)(?:,(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?-\d+(?:\.\d+)?|-\d+(?:\.\d+)?|\d+(?:\.\d+)?-|\d+(?:\.\d+)?))*(?=\D|$)$
```

See it [here on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vibd)

But splitting on the commas like Guffa suggested would be the better solution (+1)!

Comment: Thank you very much, that was exactly what I'm looking for! I think I will use both your solution and the one suggested by Guffa to make it completely failsafe and to filter out redundant parts (like 20-40,22).

Answer (score 2):

I think that you should just split them on the comma first, and validate and parse each item. There isn't any way to write a regular expression that can validate that the numbers makes sense anyway.

Consider for example input like `1,2,1,1,2` or `10-20,11-12,14-16`, where you have repeated values and overlapping ranges. You have to decide what to do with inconsistent data, like whether overlapping ranges should be allowed and merged, and whether ranges have to come in the correct order or not.